# How to show that outliers come disproportionately often from a particular group? (context: bibliometrics)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-visualization, p-value, descriptive-statistics

I got the following quandary and wondering if you have any thoughts on how to show/test it.

I work with peer review data and notice that many of the most highly cited articles in my data were "first round consensus accept" decisions, as opposed to going through 2 or more rounds of review AND/OR being no consensus.

So I want to show/test whether the peer review process picked out the really good stuff (i.e. very high subsequent citations) especially effectively (i.e. first round consensus accept).

**What's a good way to show this / what statistical test would I use?**

The only way I've thought of so far -- and which I don't like much -- is the following:
1. rank all the articles by citations.
2. show that as include in your set lower and lower cited articles, the fraction of the group that were first-round-consensus-accept decreases. i.e. the top cited articles were disproportionately often first-round consensus accept.

[image: fraction that's 1st-rd-cons-accept]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Two By Two Chart:

**Variable 1:** Y=1 (First round acceptance), Y=0 (NO first Round Acceptance)

**Variable 2:** 
Z=1 (Citations > Median # of Citations), Z=0 (Citations>Median # of Citations)

[image]

Then calculate the marginal probabilities:

**Pr (Z=1|Y=1)** = The probability of having higher citations given first round acceptance

**Pr (Z=1|Z=0)** = The probability of having higher citations given NO first round acceptance

Compare the above conditional probabilities

Comment: Thanks @subra, makes sense, but I wonder if there isn't a more continuous way to do this than divide citations into two groups (above and below the median).

Comment: @Misha: If you have more variables, you can run the following regression---->

# of citations= β0+β1 X1+β2 X2+β3 1(if accepted in first round)

You need β3 to have a positive coefficient.

Comment: Thanks @subra. That specification would tell me the (constant) effect on citations of being in group 1 vs. group 0. What I want is an effect the varies across the citation range.. showing that the higher the citations, the more likely the article to be a first-round-consensus-accept.


One thing I'm pondering is a figure like the one I showed in the OP, but with a rolling window (of citations) on the x-axis... and "fraction 1st round consensus accept" on y-axis. Still don't know what statistical test I'd want to do though.

Comment: @ Misha:  If you did a quantile regression on above specification, it will give you the effect of first round acceptance on different quantiles of (# of citations.) This way you can see the effect varying at different levels of citations.